# My photo gallery I upload multiple image with encrypted name, But I want to save these encrypted name in database

Tags: database, codeigniter, encryption, filenames

My codeigniter photo gallery upload multiple image in single click. Image upload with encrypted name but name save in database original image name.I want to save in database those encrypted name.

**My controller code is:**

```
public function file_upload2(){
    if($this->session->userdata('is_loged_in')){
        $config = array();
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['upload_path'] = './photo/'; //give the path to upload the image in folder
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|JPG';
        $config['max_size'] = 0;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required|trim');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
            $files = $_FILES;
            $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
            for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++){
                $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $this->upload->do_upload();
                $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                $images[] = $fileName;
               }
            $category = $this->input->post('category');
            $fileName = implode(',',$images);
            $this->Upload_model->upload_image($fileName,$category);
            if($this->upload->do_upload()){
            $this->success();
            }  else {
              $this->index();  
            }

        }  else {
            $this->index();
        }
     }  else {
         redirect('admin'); 
     }
}
```

**My Model:**

```
public function upload_image($fileName,$category){
  if($fileName!='' ){
        $filename1 = explode(',',$fileName);
        foreach($filename1 as $file){
           $file_data = array(
              'name' => $file,
              'datetime'=> date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
              'category'=> $category
            );
        $this->db->insert('photo', $file_data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you uploading, use the codeigniter's upload data, since php `$_FILES` array doesn't know anything about the encrypted name:

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    echo $data['file_name']; // Here is the encrypted filename
}
```